# Importing GUFW rules?

Tags: firewall

Is there an easy way to import ready rules for uncomplicated firewall?
like ready in and out rules with IPs and everything.

Answer (score 0):

UFW closes all incoming connections by default. This is enough for most of users. I mean you do not have to (and should not) import rules unless you are doing a specific job.

Say, you want use SSH in order to connect your computer in your home from the work, in this case you write a rule to open the related port. Rules will come when you need them. Using ready rule lists as you mentioned may be dangerous.